# very different file size when export data from bigquery to GCS

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am export data from BQ to GCS with the following query

```
  export_query = f"""
      EXPORT DATA
      OPTIONS(
        uri='{uri}',
        format='PARQUET',
        overwrite=true,
        compression='GZIP')
      AS {query}"""
```

and I am seeing the resulting files are of very different size, as a few of them are 10x larger than the rest. I am wondering why this happened..And how can I make sure the files all have similar size?

[image]

Comment: I guess the size of the raw export files is roughly the same, but the compression rate is different for the different files. E.g. exporting names and in one file many people have the name "Smith", then the zip programm will compress this much butter than a file with many different names.  Could you please check for the file size of two unzipped files.

Comment: @Samuel we made sure each entry(i.e. row) in the data is unique. Some of the files has 10x the number of rows than the rest. Why always 10x?

Comment: I tested it with csv and gzip. The number of rows in the files are 2498375,

2500849,

2500618, .... The zipped size ranges between some KB to some MB.

Comment: @Samuel for me I have ~400 files with ~20000 rows, with size around 450KB, and ~50 files with ~200000 rows, with size ~4.2MB. These are not some random numbers and I am just not sure why it's like this..

Comment: @Ryan,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports the maximum table size exported to a single file is 1 GB. For exporting data more than 1 GB, a wildcard can be used to export the data into multiple files. When exporting data to multiple files the size of the file varies as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#export_jobs).You can check for the possible options for the destinationUris property in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files).

When you export data to multiple files, the size of the files will vary, this is because the number of files will depend on the number of workers that are starting to export a table/query to GCS in parquet format. However, combining the results in one file would require an additional shuffling step to ensure that all of the data ends up on the same partition, which is not something that BigQuery currently does.
If you want to customize the number of files then you need to use dataflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I don't understand is the non-deterministic behavior that a small number of the files are 10x larger than the rest. I was expecting the resulting files to have random sizes in some range..